# Is there a way to switch between which node I want active from a main node that monitors the robot?

Tags: ros, rospy

Im still learning the basics of ROS. So I have a main navigator node that monitors a robot and what I want is for the main node to stop at lets say an obstacle and switch to a separate node that will give the Twist commands to go around the object and then switch back to a separate node for the rest of the navigation. Is there some sort of ros command for node switching?

Comment: The posted solution mentions terminating and relaunching a node. This will add overhead and unnecessary complexity for the application described. Have you considered looking at [the mux package](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/mux) to control inputs?

Comment: @BTables You are right, I think this is more the kind of thing I'm looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This explains how to [launch a node](https://www.theconstructsim.com/launch-node-using-ros-program/) using rospy

Then as for stopping a node as it allows two nodes to know when the other has terminated, [bond](http://wiki.ros.org/bond) should do what you want

Comment: Just a note: for the application OP explained you should 100% not be terminating and relaunching nodes.